# Using functions in Java (not methods)

Tags: java, oop

Is it possible to use functions in Java? I'm not used to OOP and I like having global functions that can be used in any classes. Is this possible in Java? Right now, I have a class named `$` that contains all my functions (as static methods). Is there a Java convention for using classes like this? (I borrowed the `$` from JQuery)

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529603/any-risk-using-a-single-dollar-sign-as-a-java-class-name).

Comment: you can use static import and use functions without any prefix in any class http://viralpatel.net/blogs/static-import-java-example-tutorial/

Comment: Don't use Java if you intend to code as if you were using JavaScript. Use JavaScript instead.

Comment: JavaScript is also object oriented and it is as useless as Java if you do not want to learn something new :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write static class methods with no state, which is effectively a pure function. You can do a "static import" so you don't have to reference the enclosing class. However all your methods/functions must be defined in a class. So, yes, you can do those things, but the syntax isn't perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Java encapsulates everything in classes. You must have all functions within a class. You can either have one big class with many functions and program your Java program more or less like you are writing C or have static functions/class method.

For instance you can have a class Gloabls where you put all your functions:

```
class Globals {
    public static int AddNumbers(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
}

class MyClass {
    public MyClass { int four = Globals.AddNumbers(1,3); }
    public static void main(String[] args) { new MyClass(); }
}
```