# Nested static class name starting with $

Tags: java

I have seen some codebases where people have wrote nested static classes with names starting with "$" ? What is the significance of that ?

```
class A {
  int a;

  static class $B {
    int b;  
  }
}
```

Comment: No. Its not auto-generated.

Comment: Then produce a real example.

Comment: Related, possibly an indirect duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529603/any-risk-using-a-single-dollar-sign-as-a-java-class-name

Comment: There's another possible explanation.  The code author is obsessed with money.  Maybe we should give this convention a name.  How about trumping?  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no significance. `$` is a valid character for a java name; there's nothing special about it.

[JLS Chapter 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), which defines valid class name characters (more-or-less most "non syntax" characters, first char not a digit) even specifically cautions against this very situation:

> The `$` sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems

See [JLS Chapter 6: Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html) too.

This is just a local naming convention, perhaps to remind/indicate to developers that the class is an inner class.

Although it's a style thing, AFAICT the general consensus of the dev community is to *not* encode meta data into a name. Other examples I have seen are leading underscores for member variables/parameters, and the awful [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Try to give things good **undecorated** names.

Answer (score 2):

People generally haven't written them themselves; those are usually autogenerated somewhere. From [JLS 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

The dollar sign is a legitimate character, but it is a *very* strong convention, on par with using capital letters for class names, not to use it in ordinary code.

A handful of people use it to indicate an inner class, but I personally have never once seen the `$` character used for anything that did not also carry the *synthetic* flag, and I would consider it on par with using Hungarian notation in Java.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the significance of that ?

You would have to ask the person who wrote the code what the significance is.

However, there is no significance from the Java language perspective; i.e. the Java compiler places no special meaning on the dollar sign.  (It is just another legal identifier character, albeit one that you are *recommended* not to use; see [JLS 3.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)).

However, I *suspect* that the reason that the dollar character is that:

- The code has at some point been decompiled from bytecodes.  I say this because the Java compiler uses `A$B` as that synthetic name for a nested class `B` declared in `A`.
- The person / people who have modified / maintained it since then either don't know about or don't care about standard Java style conventions.

It could also be a (deliberate) "local convention".

Either way, most Java programmers would find this objectionable.  Don't copy it.